# Swift 4.1 : "self used method call 'defaultConfiguration' before 'super.init' call"

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.1

I'm trying to integrate a library in my project , here's the link to github https://github.com/rinov/YoutubeKit/tree/0.1.2

but i am getting this error "self used method call 'defaultConfiguration' before 'super.init' call" in those two methods

```
public init(frame: CGRect = .zero, playerVars: [String: AnyObject]) {
    super.init(frame: frame, configuration: defaultConfiguration())

    commonInit()
    self.playerVars = playerVars
}


public init(frame: CGRect = .zero, playerVars: [VideoEmbedParameter] = []) {
    super.init(frame: frame, configuration: defaultConfiguration())

    commonInit()
    guard !playerVars.isEmpty else { return }
    var params: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
    playerVars.forEach {
        let property = $0.property
        params[property.key] = property.value
    }
    self.playerVars = params
}
```

any help please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found fork with updated to **Swift 4.1** code [here](https://github.com/jayhuo/YoutubeKit).
And [here](https://github.com/jayhuo/YoutubeKit/commit/93edd51acc4fecb5140b2c58d0c473ed63b39060) you can find commit which fixes your error.

You can install this fork by just adding this line:

```
pod 'YoutubeKit', :git => 'https://github.com/jayhuo/YoutubeKit.git'
```